# How to visualize a function with four arguments?

Tags: visualization

If I have a function, `f[a, b, c, d]`, with a, b, c and d varying between 0 and 1 continuously. What would be the best way to explore this function visually with *Mathematica*? Is evaluating multiple `Plot3D` expressions with two of the four arguments held constant my only option?

Answer (score 12):

For example:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[Norm[{x, y, z}]^ (3 + w), 
               {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
               ContourStyle -> (Directive[Opacity[.3, #]] & /@ {Red, Green, Cyan}),
               Contours -> {1, 2, 3}, MeshStyle -> None], 
{w, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice!!! Further examples plus mathematical proofs can be found in the last 3 chapters of [link](http://www.amazon.com/Differential-Geometry-Mathematica-Textbooks-Mathematics/dp/1584884487)

Comment: I'm having difficulties interpreting the contour surfaces in this plot. What do they represent exactly? How can I get a feeling of how my function behaves from the contour surfaces?

Comment: @su1 "get a feeling" is quite vague :) What exactly do you want to explore?

Comment: for example understand from the contour surfaces how my output varies when x increases, knowing all other inputs are fixed. Basically I don't really know how to read a ContourPlot3D. It's easier to read it when it's in the form `ContourPlot3D[f==g, ...]` but when in the form of `ContourPlot3D[f, ...]` I don't know what the plot represents

Comment: @su1 In the form I used the function you've three contours: On the red one the function value is `1`, on the green one the value of the function is `2` and in the cyan contour the function evaluates to `3`.Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it's clear. What about when you don't specify the Contours? What surface is plotted by default?

Comment: @su1  http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Contours.html

Answer (score 4):

Manipulate is a great tool anyway:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[
  c - Sin[d] - a x^2 - b y^2 + z^2 == x y z, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 
   2}, {z, -2, 2}, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]], 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.75]], {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, {d,
   0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, what you're visualizing there is a function of *seven* arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The method you mention, using the Plot3D expressions, may be implemented pair-wise. That is: represent twin spaces (a,b,f) and (c,d,f), display the fixed values (a1,b1,0) and (c1,d1,0), and the functions f(a,b,c1,d1) and f(a1,b1,c,d), in their corresponding space. Next step, treat the "fixed" values as slider ("pilot") values, and plot the corresponding functions accordingly, letting them evolve "in real time" with their "pilot" values.
I've done this with another tool, see Youtube demo at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_h8tlTxRos

Comment: Please provide actual code in your answer.